# Specifying name of rails partial to render using a variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible in Rails 3.0 to render a partial where the name of the partial is stored in a variable?

I am attempting something similar to:

```
<%= escape_javascript(raw render :partial => @partial_name, :locals => { :value => @value} )%>
```

**Updated with more details**

In my application I have a set of models using multi-table inheritance, for example lets say I have a base model 'cupcake' and variants such as 'AwesomeCupcake' and 'AlrightCupcake'.

Each of these models have their own custom partial for displaying information and follow the naming scheme: '_awesome_cupcake' and '_alright_cupcake'.

On a page I have links to each type of cupcake in which I want the controller to accept a parameter and dynamically derive which partial to render.  The following works as wanted if (in the new.js.erb file) I replace '@partial_name' with something such as 'awesome_cupcake'.

Here is a little more information into how my components are laid out:

**application.js**

```
$('#set_cupcake').click(function () {
   $.getScript('/cupcakes/new.js?cupcake_type=awesome');
});
```

**cupcakes_controller.rb**

```
def new
   cupcake_type = "#{params[:cupcake_type].capitalize}Cupcake"

   if Object.const_defined? cupcake_type
     @cupcake = cupcake_type.constantize.new
     @partial_name = "#{params[:cupcake_type]}_cupcake"
   end
end
```

**views/cupcakes/new.js.erb**

```
$('#cupcakes')
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(raw render :partial => @partial_name, :locals => { :cupcake => @cupcake } ) %>")
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I have added additional information regarding my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the issue was.  In my controller I was setting the @partial_name within the scope of a condition that was checking if a specific model existed.

I did not realize that using Object.const_defined? doesn't really work for rails in development mode as the models aren't initially all loaded.  An alternate approach I found is to search through a list of database table connections using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.

However I think a better solution is to store some file that 'registers' acceptable values for this parameter.

Comment: That would have been a pretty hard thing to track down. Kudos!

Comment: Can't you just rescue from the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Make sure @partial_variable is a string of the name (such as "header" and it will work fine.

Comment: I am building a string from a parameter and storing that into the @partial_name variable.  I have added some additional details to my question that hopefully will better explain what I am attempting to do.

Comment: The error that I get is: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class).  If I hard code the name of a partial it works but if I copy that same string into a variable I get an error.

Comment: Do me a favour and type this as the last item in your controller. `raise @partial_name`

Answer (score 0):

If that's not working, can you show us exactly what @partial_name contains? What error are you getting?

Make sure that the leading underscore is left out, as well as the file extension.

For example: to render '_myPartial.html.erb', @partial_name should be "myPartial".